# Cross domain ajax request from javascript file without help of server side code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am consuming service of random.org, (I want to get the numbers from random.org site using url). I am fetching data using ajax from my JavaScript. So how to make cross domain ajax call from my domain (and avoid permission error)? I want solution without help of server side code (sever proxy). Example code will be great help for me.

Comment: If they do not offer a JSON service, it is not going to happen.

Comment: Have you considered YQL or Yahoo pipes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lobby the owner of random.org to provide a [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) API - that's the only way to make this happen.

Answer (score 3):

Just sent an email to random.org and received this reply

> Thanks for your email.  Yes, I am working on a JSONP interface.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Mads

Answer (score 1):

You need a server proxy on your domain, or it won't happen. Here's a [summary](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj/) of cross-domain ajax techniques, the only 'real' non-proxy solution, as RichieHindle pointed out, being **jsonp**. But that requires you to be buddies with the guys at random.org, or for them to have a compelling reason to enable it for you.

Comment: Is there any other way to overcome it ?