# JavaScript - Math.random() - parameter

Tags: javascript, math, random

What changes adding the parameter in `Math.random()`?

For example:

```
Math.random() == Math.random(1234)
```

Comment: please give example of what you are implying?

Comment: Is it possible to add parameters to math.random()

Comment: A simple case of RTM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random (in particular, that part that says "parameters: none")

Comment: `math.random()` should throw a `ReferenceError`. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Math.random` doesn't take params.

If you want to generate a random number between 2 intervals (a and b) you can use the formula:

```
math.random()*(b-a)+a
```

Comment: See also [Make JavaScript Math.random() useful](http://www.shawnolson.net/a/789/make_javascript_mathrandom_useful.html).

Comment: why +a at the end? I don't understand why that is important. Entering Math.floor(Math.random() * (100-1)) will give you a number between 1 and 100...

Answer (score 9):

Read the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

> #### 15.8.2.14 random ( )
>
> Returns a number value with positive sign, greater than
> or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen
> randomly or pseudo randomly with
> approximately uniform distribution
> over that range, using an
> implementation-dependent algorithm or
> strategy. **This function takes no
> arguments.**

Comment: Highlighted relevant portion :)

Answer (score 5):

Nothing.  There is no seed for `Math.random` in Javascript.  Anything inside the function call will just be dropped.

Answer (score 4):

No official parameters. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

The confusion is understandable. Several sites have a seed in the function since it came from C / Java. More information about this ignored parameter here: [Math.random() - Not random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972550/math-random-not-random)

If you want a better random number get one from here http://www.random.org/clients/http/ - you will need to wrap it in some server based client - see here for more information [Cross domain ajax request from javascript file without help of server side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960624/cross-domain-ajax-request-from-javascript-file-without-help-of-server-side-code)

UPDATE: Emailed the creator of random.org - he replied he is working on a jsonp implementation...

Answer (score 3):

It will just ignore the passed parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't - `Math.random()` doesn't take any parameters... :)

Comment: and how can i make a stronger random or other random?

Comment: A "stronger random"? I'm afraid you've lost me... If you mean random between a different range, check [Parkyprg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/347807/parkyprg)'s answer.